# What NPN transistor should I use?

Tags: arduino, transistors, datasheet, npn

I need to control a 12 V 5 A (or 3 A if need be) with an Arduino UNO which has 5 V and 40 mA. Unfortunately I don't know how to read transistor data sheets. What NPN transistor should I get for this project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use an NPN transistor for this project. There are parts out there that will work by an N channel, logic level MOSFET is a better choice. It's \$R_{DS}\$ in saturation will be very small, and it won't waste power as heat. Take a look at a part like [this one](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/IRF3709ZPBF/IRF3709ZPBF-ND/811202). \$R_{DS}<10m\Omega, P=I^2R = (5A)(10m\Omega) = 50mW\$ That is pretty good.

You'll implement it like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faWQSO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is R3 doing in this schematic?

Comment: That is the load you're switching.

Comment: So the point of this circuit is to use the arduino to launch a model rocket, the igniter to launch the rocket requires 12Vdc and 5A, so what would the schematic for that look like?

Comment: Exactly what I drew, just replace the resistor with the igniter.

Comment: Ah, sorry I'm not exactly experienced in electronics, what is the purpose of the diode?

Comment: That is a Schottky diode to protect the transistor from inductive flyback voltage. \$V_L(t) = L\dfrac{di}{dt}\$ causes a voltage surge with opposite polarity when the switch turns off. The diode starts to conduct, shorting the load until the condition stabilizes and the diode stops conducting.  I'm debating whether you actually need it for this application since your load is going to fail open within a few milliseconds. I need to think about it, but intuition says you could omit it and not hurt the transistor.

Comment: I have a diode laying around, it wouldn't hurt to have it in right? From what I understood you needed a diode for then when you have something like a DC motor

Comment: It is essential for any inductive load.

Comment: Would a relay work for this too?

Comment: That is another question in itself. Yes it would, but it would probably be more complicated that my circuit, depending on which relay you used.

Comment: What does R1 do?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-up_resistor